# Return single row from joined tables where > 1 rows in child table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have several tables, `books, bookcategories, categories`

`bookcategories` is a join table to allow the many to many relationship between `books` and `categories`.

I want to be able to run a category search on books such that the search returns one row per book even when the book has many categories.

**Books**

```
ID   | Title
1    | Once upon...
2    | How many...
3    | How much...
```

**Categories**

```
ID   | Category
1    | x
2    | y
3    | z
```

**BookCategories**

```
   BookId | CategoryId
     1    |     1
     1    |     2
     2    |     2
     2    |     3
     2    |     1
     3    |     1
```

I thought I could get away with this:

```
SELECT  b.Id,
    b.Title,
FROM    ( books b
    INNER JOIN bookcategories bc ON b.ID= bc.BookId
    )
WHERE (bc.categoryId =1 AND bc.categoryId=2)
GROUP BY b.Id, b.Title
```

but as soon as I add the AND, the query returns no rows. But that is the criteria I need to apply - I only want to return book rows where the book has both category 1 and 2 as above (i.e. not category 1 OR category 2)

Can't help thinking that I am missing something quite basic. Can anyone help?

Do I need to change the structure of the tables or is there a way of achieving what I need.

Wing

Comment: I think you need to re-word your question. The text before the code samples tells a slightly different story than the code after your code samples (as evidenced by the two answers which give different results). Instead of trying to explain this in words, can you show us exactly which rows should be returned from your sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should return books that have both category one and two:

```
select  b.Id
,       b.Title
from    books b
join    bookcategories bc
on      bc.BookId = b.Id
group by
         b.Id
,        b.Title
having   sum(case when bc.categoryId = 1 then 1 end) > 0
         and sum(case when bc.categoryId = 2 then 1 end) > 0
```

Alternatively, you can use a double `exists` clause:

```
select  b.Id
,       b.Title
from    books b
where   exists
        (
        select  *
        from    bookcategories bc
        where   bc.BookId = b.Id
                and bc.CategoryId = 1
        )
        and exists
        (
        select  *
        from    bookcategories bc
        where   bc.BookId = b.Id
                and bc.CategoryId = 2
        )
```

Comment: Thanks Andomar - have now implemented using second example above.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative (at least based on what I *think* you want):

```
SELECT ID, Title
FROM 
(
  SELECT b.ID, b.Title, c = COUNT(bc.BookID)
  FROM dbo.Books AS b
  INNER JOIN dbo.BookCategories AS bc
  ON b.ID = bc.BOokID
  AND bc.CategoryID IN (1,2)
  GROUP BY b.ID, b.Title
) AS x
WHERE c >= 2; -- in case there is no unique constraint on BookCategories
```

Though this should work also:

```
SELECT b.ID, b.Title
  FROM dbo.Books AS b
  INNER JOIN dbo.BookCategories AS bc
  ON b.ID = bc.BOokID
  AND bc.CategoryID IN (1,2)
GROUP BY b.ID, b.Title
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
```

Comment: Thanks these both work as well although have already implemented using the exists example from Andomar. Thanks a lot anyway - really helpful have learned a lot about subqueries. W

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `select distinct` and changing the `and` to an `or`.

```
SELECT      DISTINCT b.Id, b.Title
FROM        books b
INNER JOIN  bookcategories bc ON b.ID= bc.BookId
WHERE       (bc.categoryId=1 OR bc.categoryId=2)
ORDER BY    b.ID
```

The `distinct` keyword will NOT return duplicate rows; so you can now use `categoryID = 1 OR categoryID = 2`.

Comment: This doesnt do what I need it to do unfortunately.  The above does not exclude books that do not have both categories.